# thymeleaf error - Sum two numbers via Thymleaf and Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, thymeleaf

I'm trying to request two numbers (first and second) as input via a form using Thymeleaf, and have the numbers added and the answer returned.  The code is run from:
   http://localhost:8080/add

I've based the program on this link:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

I'm also using the latest version of Springboot, currently 1.5.8.

I'm finding this simple task becoming somewhat convoluted (compared to say python), with continual errors that aren't making any sense. My current problem is I'm getting the following error, which even after checking similar posts online, I can't resolve...

Error:
"Exception processing template "add": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'"

Based on these posts I've change "long" to "Long" in my NumberForm, and moved my NumberForm.java under "sec.calculator", but no joy...

- Any help would be appreciated !

Here's my code:

1) src/main/java

CalculatorController.java:

```
package sec.calculator;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class CalculatorController {

  @GetMapping("/add")
  public String addForm(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("add", new NumberForm());
     return "add";
  }

  @PostMapping("/add")
  public String addSubmit(@ModelAttribute NumberForm add) {
     return "result";
  }
}
```

## ------------------------------------

CalculatorApplication.java

```
package sec.calculator;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CalculatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(CalculatorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

## ------------------------------------

NumberForm.java

```
package sec.calculator;
```

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
/**import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
*/

public class NumberForm {
    @NotNull
    @Min(0)
    private Long first;
    private Long second;

    public Long add_out;

    public Long add_output() {
        return add_out ;
    }

    public void Setfirst(Long first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public void Setsecond(Long second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

## -----------------------------------

2) src/main/resources/templates

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
            <body>
                <h1>Form</h1>
                    <form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${NumberForm}" method="post">
                    <p>First: <input type="text" th:field="*{First}" /></p>
                    <p>Second: <input type="text" th:field="*{Second}" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>
```

## ------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

There are several issues here.  In particular, Java is very much case-sensitive.

1. Follow the [convention](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) for setters so that Thymeleaf can
   understand it:

   ```
   public void setFirst(Long first) {
       this.first = first;
   }

   public void setSecond(Long second) {
       this.second = second;
   }
   ```

   I am assuming you left out the analogous getter methods.

   Even better, see Project Lombok - stop the madness entirely and use
   `@Setter` and `@Getter` or `@Data`.
2. In your form, lower-case your field names:

   ```
   <p>First: <input type="text" th:field="*{first}" /></p>
   <p>Second: <input type="text" th:field="*{second}" /></p>
   ```

   I'd also stay away from variable names like these since they can become very confusing.
3. Also in your form, you are using `th:object="${NumberForm}"` but
   you named your variable `add`.  Thymeleaf knows nothing about this variable named `NumberForm`.  Your variable is named `add` of a type `NumberForm`, but Thymeleaf will need the name of the variable here.

   So you can do: `model.addAttribute("numberForm", new NumberForm());`

   and `th:object="${numberForm}"`

   Using lower-case for your `th:object` (modelAttribute) is by
   convention.
4. You'll actually need to include some code to sum the values.  I'll
   leave that part for you.